# Wordpress Custom Menu Error

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a custom menu for [wordpress](http://www.botkai.com/baseball/), and I'm having a few problems.

I have 3 other menu's that work perfectly using this code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
            'top-menu' => __( 'Top Menu' ),
            'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
            'baseball-menu' => __( 'Baseball Menu' ),
        )
    );
}
```

However the problem is that even when I add the menu in the admin panel, the wrong menu shows up when I call for this -Baseball menu- on a custom page.

[Image of menu's](http://www.botkai.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/menus.png)

This is the code I used to call the Baseball menu, however when I check the page, what shows up is the normal Navigation menu.

I'm running out of ideas. What could be causing this problem?

```
<?php 
    /* Template Name: Baseball Page */

get_header(); ?>

            <!-- BEGIN MAIN WRAPPER -->
            <div id="main-wrapper">

            <div>

                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => false, 'theme-location' => 'baseball-menu' ) ); ?>

            </div>


            </div>


            <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with the 'theme-location'.  It is using a dash instead of an underscore.

It should be 'theme_location'.

Hope that helps,

~ crw